# How can i wait for a program to end and then automatically start a second program in the Linux console?

Tags: linux, bash

How can I wait for a program to complete and then start another program automatically in another console?

EDIT: The first program can be long running and the other program should start right after the completion of the first program.

Comment: What do you mean by starting a new program in a new console? Do you mean as a separate process?

Comment: @guzmonne: yes.

Answer (score 0):

`tail -f --pid=xyzu /dev/null && second_program`

for example, in one console (terminal) invoke `cat`. In another console, use `pstree -p | grep cat` to find its process id. Then, in that other console, type `tail -f --pid=6169 /dev/null && ls` (replace the number with the correct one and use the needed command instead of `ls`). Then, end cat with `CTL-C`.

EDIT: Another example is, you want to shutdown the computer automatically when a long running program has completed:

first, find the pid of the long running program:

`pstree -p | grep long_running_program`
For instance, you find the pid `3373`. Now, use the command:
`sudo tail -f --pid=3373 /dev/null && shutdown -h now`

Comment: Your question is not clear without the details you wrote in this answer. You should explain **in the question** that you start a long-running program in one console *A* and in a different console *B* you want to type a command that will wait for the end of the process that was started in *A* and then run a command in *B*.

Comment: Read about tmux to run commands inside the "one" and "another" consoles. For the "another console", you need several steps so you'll go easier if you create a bash script.